# override a class property

Tags: html, css

i have this line:

```
echo "<td class='td_show_contact_item' color='#ff0000' align='left'>".link_to($msg->getSubject(),   'messagebox/read?cursor='.$cursor,'class=link_medium_red')."</td>";
```

i cannot find where td_show_contact_item is defined?? i grep'd it but found nothing so i want to just override the color property as it is now the link text is blue and only when you hover over it displays red..i want the link text red please?

thank you

Comment: Look at all the linked CSS files that are on that page. Alternatively, use the developer tools or firebug to find out exactly what rules are defined in what CSS file. It is possibly that the rule is not defined.

Comment: Use Firebug and inspect that element on the page. That'll show you where, if atall, .td_show_contact_item is defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find `td_show_contact_item` you could use FireFox FireBug plugin.

To change the color of this element, you could write it inline like:

```
<td class='td_show_contact_item' style='color:#FF0000 !important;' align='left'>
```

Or add a second class:

```
.td_class, .td_class a, .td_class a:visited
{
   color:#FF0000 !important;
}

<td class='td_show_contact_item td_class' align='left'>
```

Notice `!important` has been added to ensure the current style is overridden.

Comment: thanks i see it does change the color in FF but when i view in chrome it is still the same????

Comment: Please see edit. I've changed CSS to apply to link and visited links too

Comment: thanks but i cannot change the original td_show_contact_item class cos it is used many other places..all works fine if i do: 

    style='color:#FF0000 !important;'
    
EXCEPT in chrome???? how now?
thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's best to do this via .css, since the link-color is not the same as the td color.

If it's really not defined, you can add the td_show_contact_item to your css file, and change the link-color for links within

```
.td_show_contact_item a {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

(Perhaps, add `.td_show_contact_item a:visited` as well)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<td class='td_show_contact_item' style='color=#ff0000; text-align=left'>"
  .link_to($msg->getSubject(),   'messagebox/read?cursor='.$cursor,'class=link_medium_red')."</td>";
```